# Selecting data in my SQL and grouping it by time intervals

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with a SQL statement I need for a chart I am doing in HighChart.

Below is the SQL statement I use now, where I use `nrOfCalls` and `veryGood` to calculate the effiency of the callcenter staff. Basically I need to group my results in intervals of 15 minutes from a Unix timestamp throughout a workday, instead of the total for a whole day.

```
SELECT queue, 
      SUM(IF(verb='CONNECT',1,0)) as nrOfCalls ,
      SUM(IF(data1<=60,1,0)) AS veryGood,
      date(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_id)) as xAxis 
FROM queue_log 
WHERE verb = 'CONNECT' 
AND time_id > 1345680001 
AND time_id < 1346457599 
AND queue IN (
    20201, 20202, 20203, 20204, 20205, 20206, 20207, 20208, 20209, 20210, 20211, 20212
) 
GROUP BY xAxis
```

I've tried to search the web and stackoverflow but I cant see to find anything that suits the problem I'm faced with.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.
- Nicolai

Comment: What dbms are you using (e.g. SQL-Server,Oracle,MySql)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write is the xAxis should be ordered ascending or descending

Comment: Sorry... when groub by you need to write it

Comment: not really, the above statement works fine, it need altering to select the data in timeintervals of 15 mins instead of just grouping everything for a whole day